# Compare vector values in GAMS

Tags: vector, compare, gams-math

Is it possible to compare two vectors in GAMS directly? For example,

```
set i 'plants' /i0*i9/
parameter a(i),b(i);
a(i)=uniformint(1,9);
b(i)=uniformint(1,9);
if(a(i)=b(i),
display a;
else
display b;
);
```

Directly using this code will result in errors. However, is it possible to use comparison of two vectors in my if condition?
Thanks, Sophia

Answer (score 0):

While your conditional expression looks right, there is a loop over `i` missing.
This could look like the following:

```
Loop (i,
  if(a(i)=b(i),
    display a;
  else
    display b;
  );
);
```